# Loop through validation errors, and display the right one - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a registration system, and I need to display any validation errors that come up. Most of my validation is being checked by JavaScript because I'm using the Semantic-UI Framework. But there is 2 custom validation rules that I cant really display in the JavaScript, so I need to see which of those two error messages it is, and flash the correct error message.

Here is my Register function with the validation:

```
 public function postRegister (Request $request) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'username' => 'unique:users',
            'email'    => 'unique:users',
            'password' => '',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            flash()->error('Error', 'Either your username or email is already take. Please choose a different one.');
            return back();
        }

        // Create the user in the Database.
        User::create([
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'username' => $request->input('username'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
            'verified' => 0,
        ]);

        // Flash a info message saying you need to confirm your email.
        flash()->overlay('Info', 'You have successfully registered. Please confirm your email address in your inbox.');

        return redirect()->back();
```

As you can see there are two custom error messages, and If a user gets just one of them wrong, it will flash my Sweet-alert modal with that message.

How can I maybe loop through my error message and  see which one I get wrong, and display a specific flash message to that error?

Comment: You can simply parse $validator->messages()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve an array of all validator errors, you can use the `errors` method:

```
$messages = $validator->errors();
//Determining If Messages Exist For A Field
if ($messages->has('username')) {
    //Show custom message
}
if ($messages->has('email')) {
    //Show custom message
}
```